# which book can you prefer for sql performance tuning with mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance

I found the MySQL Performance Tuning Book (link below) but i think i need something more specific in query tuning.

[http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Jeremy-Zawodny/dp/0596003064/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1291639807&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003064)

has anybody some good suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion one of the best available [resources](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716):

[image: High Performance MySQL: Optimization, Backups, Replication, and More]

Comment: i would need something more specific for queries. i think this book is good for sysadmins not for developers.

Comment: +1 For linking the 2nd Edition over the 1st Edition; by-and-large, it's a totally different book.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd edition now for 2012

http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1449314287?ie=UTF8&camp=213733&creative=393185&creativeASIN=1449314287&linkCode=shr&tag=mifi06-20&qid=1352930089&sr=8-1